# Запрос контакта у пользователя

Tags: telegram, aiogram, бот

Помогите написать код для бота который будет запрашивать номер у пользователя телеграм
Бот: Нажмите на кнопку ниже, чтобы отправить контакт
Пользователь: Жмёт кнопку и отправляет свой контакт
Бот: ...

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? вам следует прочитать "как задавать вопросы" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы самостоятельно пытались разобраться? Что у вас не получилось?

Вот пример хендлера с кнопкой отправки контакта боту:

```
@dp.message(Command("contact"))
async def contact_buttons(message: types.Message):
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.row(
        types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить контакт", request_contact=True)
    )
    await message.answer(
        "Нажми на кнопку:",
        reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True),
    )
```

Comment: не думаю что можно было показать решение, когда он кажется даже не пытался что либо сделать. Он не задал вопрос в типе "сделал то-то а получилось как то вот так", больше похож на заказ фрилансерам XD

Comment: @CraSmi ну, в общем виде хендлер я показал. Может сам дальше разберется